# Use converter with WPF Localization Extension

Tags: wpf, localization, converters

I want to use a custom converter on the translated content, e.g. I have now:

```
Content="{lex:LocText Library:Language:Overview}"
```

But I want to add a Converter (**IValueConverter**) to it (as you can do with **Binding**). How to achieve this? The documentation on this plugin is kinda 'empty'.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to add a converter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WPF Localization Extension 2.1 does now support a wire range of new possibilities including your needs.

http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com/

Comment: I fail to see how linking to the original project answers this question, but ok.

Answer (score 0):

Why not bind to a "classic" .resx resource file instead?
This is quite easy in WPF. Just create the resource file and display the text like this:

```
...
<GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static Properties:Strings.UserName}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding UserName}"/>
...
```

Here Header looks up "UserName" in Strings.resx placed in the "Properties" namespace.
The properties namespace alias is defined like this:

```
<Window x:Class="MyControls.MyWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:pwc="clr-namespace:PostalWpfControls"
        xmlns:Properties="clr-namespace:MyWpfControls.Properties"
...
```

Comment: That would mean I don't have the translation anymore by the Localization Extension. I'm looking for a solution which still uses that but with a converter. The WPF Localization Extension doesn't seem to allow binding unfortunately.

Comment: This way also means that the binded value WONT get updated on culture change.